# Gmail warns, "Be careful with this message." Is this an authentication problem?

Tags: civimail

I have a profile configured to send an email message to my Gmail address when someone completes the form and is added to the group.  When I open the message in Gmail I get the "Be careful" warning. That warning message interferes with part of our workflow:  automatic forwarding of the message. Can I do some reconfiguring in CiviCRM to make Gmail happy?
[image]

--Arlo

CiviCRM 5.38.0 on WordPress Version 5.8.2

Comment: can you use one of the many email testers to see if the domain the email is being sent from passes both SPF and DKIM/

Comment: Thank you. I'll check the domain that the emails are being sent from.